# Freemarker converting HTML ISO tags when reading ftl file

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to output curly quotes in an HTML file that I am generating in Freemarker. The template file contains:

```
Kevin&#8217;s
```

When the HTML file is generated, it comes out as:

```
Kevin?s
```

At first I thought that the issue was happening during the generation of the HTML file. But I was able to track down the conversion to when the template was read in. Does anyone know how to prevent Freemarker from doing this conversion when reading the template? My code for the conversion:

```
// Freemarker configuration object
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(new Version(2, 3, 21));
try
{
  cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("templates"));
  cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
  cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.HTML_DEBUG_HANDLER);

  // Load template from source folder
  Template template = cfg.getTemplate("curly.html");
  template.setEncoding("UTF-8");

  // Build the data-model
  Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  // Console output
  Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
  template.process(data, out);
  out.flush();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (TemplateException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the template file indeed contains `Kevin&#8217;s`, then the out would be `Kevin&#8217;s` too (as FreeMarker doesn't resolve HTML entities), so I suppose you mean that the character with that code is there as one character. In that case, the most probable culprit has nothing to do with FreeMarker: `new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)`. You have omitted the encoding parameter of the constructor there, so it will use the system default encoding. Even if you do specify that, your console have a fixed encoding (which is not necessarily the system default BTW). So try to write the output into a file by explicitly specifying UTF-8 for the `OutputStreamWriter`. If the output will be still wrong, then check if you have indeed used UTF-8 to create the template file, and for reading the output file.

BTW, that `template.setEncoding` is not necessary. Remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I changed my line to:


    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8");


but I am still having the same issue. I am really leaning towards where I open the template. I have not been able to track down anybody else havnig this issue so I know it must be something pretty simple that I am overlooking.

Comment: As I said, write it out to a file, not to the console. Have you tried that? Or does your console use UTF-8?

Comment: Also you haven't answered if you literally have `&#8217;` there, because that's even US-ASCII and not just one characters.